# When Does Method Resolution/Lookup Occur During Runtime?

Tags: c#

I have the following code to add debugging information to a message when in Debug mode:

**Code In Tester DLL**

```
private string GetMessage(Foo foo)
{
    var messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // add message info

#if DEBUG
    messageBuilder.AppendLine(foo.GetDebuggingInfo());
#endif

    return messageBuilder.ToString();
}
```

**Library Under Test**

C++ library called from C# via a Managed C++ Wrapper project

```
#ifdef DEBUG
string Foo::GetDebuggingInfo()
{
    ...
}
#endif
```

Now the issue I ran into is `Foo` is declared in a separate library, and `GetDebuggingInfo` is also conditionally compiled in.  And for backward compatibility reasons the tester DLL is ran against all previously released versions of the library under test to make sure the output our server sends will continue to be ingested as expected across all differently versioned clients.  The test code is then copied out to a folder, along with the desired version of the library to test, not the version the tester was compiled against.  Everything runs fine until my code reaches `GetMessage` and that's when I encounter a `MethodNotFoundException`.

My first attempt to resolve this, I thought of using reflection to make sure the function was present before calling the function, like so:

```
#if DEBUG
    if (foo.GetType().GetMethod("GetDebuggingInfo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public) != null)
        messageBuilder.AppendLine(foo.GetDebuggingInfo());
#endif
```

I figured that would keep the method from being called even when the Tester DLL is a Debug version and the DLL under Test was a release version.  Still same problem.  After adding some additional trace debugging statements, I discovered that `GetMessage` wasn't even being entered.  Upon realizing this, I tried moving the problematic method call into it's own function, and everything worked.

```
#if DEBUG
    // reflection check remains to keep the call from blowing
    // up when Tester is DEBUG and Under Test is RELEASE
    if (foo.GetType().GetMethod("GetDebuggingInfo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public) != null)
        AddDebuggingInfo(messageBuilder, foo);
#endif

#if DEBUG
private void AddDebuggingInfo(StringBuilder messageBuilder, Foo foo) =>
    messageBuilder.AppendLine(foo.GetDebuggingInfo());
#endif
```

So even though I have a working solution for my needs, I don't understand how my final solution worked, when I figured the reflection check would have been sufficient to keep the code from throwing a `MethodNotFoundException`.  So at runtime, when are methods looked up and resolved?

Comment: See my updated answer I added 2 other options you can use as work arounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects get "bound" when the container for that object is JITed, normally a function will be JITed the first time it is executed.

When you moved GetDebuggingInfo in to  AddDebuggingInfo the call to GetDebuggingInfo would only be attempted to be bound and fail if you actually entered the AddDebuggingInfo method.

Another workaround is you can defer the binding even later if you declare the variable `dynamic`

```
#if DEBUG
    dynamic tmpFoo = foo;
    if (foo.GetType().GetMethod("GetDebuggingInfo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public) != null)
        messageBuilder.AppendLine(tmpFoo.GetDebuggingInfo());
#endif
```

The dynamic causes the binding to happen at the callsite of the function instead of at the enterence of the containing function.

Another option is just use the `MethodInfo` you are checking for null to invoke.

```
#if DEBUG
    var info = foo.GetType().GetMethod("GetDebuggingInfo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    if (info != null)
    {
        var text = (string)info.Invoke(foo, null);
        messageBuilder.AppendLine(text);
    } 
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`[ConditionalAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

It does what your `#if .... #endif` code does, but it also removes calls to the decorated methods.

One limitation: the decorated methods must return `void`.  So, you'd end up passing the `StringBuilder` in as a parameter.

> Applying ConditionalAttribute to a method indicates to compilers that a call to the method should not be compiled into Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) unless the conditional compilation symbol that is associated with ConditionalAttribute is defined. You will get a compilation error in Visual Studio if you apply this attribute to a method that does not return void.

```
static void Main()
{    
    var sb = new StringBuilder();           
    Console.WriteLine("Calling AppendDebugInfo1");
    AppendDebugInfo1(sb);
    Console.WriteLine("Calling AppendDebugInfo2");
    AppendDebugInfo2(sb);
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
}

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void AppendDebugInfo1(StringBuilder sb)
{
    sb.AppendLine("DEBUG is defined");
}

[Conditional("DEBUG"), Conditional("SUPERDEBUG"))]  
public static void AppendDebugInfo2(StringBuilder sb)
{
    sb.AppendLine("DEBUG or SUPERDEBUG is defined! whoaaaaa!");
}
```

Comment: I could certainly use the `ConditionalAttribute` on my `AddDebuggingInfo` method, but the use of it won't resolve my underlying problem.  1)  My Test DLL is used against all previous released versions of the DLL under Test -- which will fail in development because the Test DLL is DEBUG and the DLL under test is RELEASE.  2)  My DLL under test is C++ being accessed via a managed C++ wrapper

Comment: I tried using `ConditionalAttribute` however I can't use it, as even when building in RELEASE mode the compiler still wants to resolve the function call to the debug info function in the other DLL.